# set objects properties in php like you would in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, oop, methods, properties

In jQuery plugins we can pass an anonymous object with properties.

```
$('selecter').function({property: 'value', property: 'value'})
```

in the plug in code jquery has a function called extend. what this does is it will take 2 objects as parameters and then overwrite object 1's properties with the properties from object 2.

Is there a way to do this or something similar in php without the use of arrays?

Comment: Why don't you want to use arrays? JavaScript's objects are very much like PHP's arrays.

Comment: Why not arrays using array_merge or array_merge_recursive? Associative arrays in PHP are pretty much the equivalent of JavaScript objects.

Comment: I prefer it not to be an array because I would have to use associative arrays which is more to type in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objects just instances of `stdClass` - you can do just

```
$result = (object)array_merge((array)$a, (array)$b);
```

Otherwise just traverse one object in a loop and assign its properties to another object.

```
foreach (get_object_vars($b) as $key => $val) {
    $a->{$key} = $val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In php 5.4  you will be able to use the short syntax for arrays:

```
$obj = new obj(['property' => 'value']);
```

and then "merge" it in  a constructor as @zerkms suggested ;)